# Geoserver authkey configuration question

Tags: geoserver, security

I'm running geoserver 2.8.0 in tomcat7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Could anybody help me with the security configuration? 
I want to serve WMS and WFS from a specific workspace using authorization based on a authkey in the URL - GET request.

I have tried to follow these instructions: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/authkey/index.html

So far I tried:

- create new Group Service: **sh_group**  (jdbc), add new User: **sh1**
  (role: **READ**)
- create Data Security rule for new workspace, access mode read for role: **READ**
- add new Authentication Filter: **sh_authfilter** (authkey), using group service **sh_group**
- add **sh_authfilter** to default Filter Chain as first selected filter (above basic and anonymous)
- create new Authentication Provider: **sh_authprovider** and add this to selected Provider Chain (top)

The synchonisation of authkeys is working and I see a UUID for the user **sh1**.
I can login to the web admin interface as user **sh1**, however I cannot access a WMS or WFS using the authkey variable in the GET request. Can you tell me above all procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to create and exception rule only applicable to getMap requests. 
look at this reference link:  http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/commit/a5985f42bd9ebe985310ae83252b4cb32e45fb1b

Comment: Thanks, but I still have no idea what to do. Does the fact that I run geoserver inside tomcat7 make a difference? And the jvm version, does that have to be jre8 (using openjdk7 atm).

Comment: Excellent - I worked it out. Had to change the url to: .../geoserver/scotland_data/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&authkey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&version=1.1.1&layers=scotland_data:pub_communitycouncils&styles=&srs=EPSG:27700&bbox=0513.16443043435,526464.9268837326,482425.4722358609,1232643.830088544&width=400&height=330&format=image/png    And the authkey now works. (without 'request=GetMap' in the url it doesn't work..).